# Python is not recognizing my variables, but instead replacing them with zero

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
change = 0
count = 0
value = 0
answer = 0

def numberTest():
    if change == 0:
        skip()
    else:
        value = change

def skip():
    count + 1
    number = value
    # Check if the input is valid
    if value != number:
        print('PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER!!!')
    else:
        Even = number % 2
    if Even == 0:
        print('Substituting even number in: x / 2')
        print('%s/2=' % number)
        answer = number / 2
    else:
        print('Substituting odd number in: 3x + 1')
        print('3' + number + ' + 1=')
        answer = number * 3
        answer = answer + 1
    answer = str(answer)
    print(''+ answer +'')
    if answer == 1:
        finalValue()
    else:
        check()

def check():
    value = answer
    skip()

def loop():
    value = int(input('Input a number: '))
    change = value
    skip()
loop()


def finalValue():
    print('The number (' + change + ') returned as 1.')
    print('A total of (' + count + ') commands were executed.')
    change = change + 1
    count = 0
    print('')
    print('')
    print('')
    numberTest()
```

Whenever I start the code, I am asked to enter a number (as expected), but then this happens:

```
Input a number: 1
Substituting even number in: x / 2
0/2=
0.0
```

I really do not understand why the program is not working as I expected, but there is one part of the code that I am suspicious of:

```
value = int(input('Input a number: '))
```

I also wrote this myself, and I am new to Python, I have only previously worked with batch, so transitioning was quite easy, though I am not very familiar with some of the commands...

**EDIT**
What I was expecting the program to do was ask for a number, store that number, then run it through a series of tests, but when the number gets to the actual tests, it substitutes "x" for "0", even if I type in a number such as "54656". Maybe, when it asks for the number, when I input the number, it just doesn't store it right, or something is wrong with my code...

Comment: The first line in the `skip()` method is not incrementing `count` if that is what you intended.

Comment: And there's a lot of mess here, you don't even need half of the variables.

Comment: well, as I said, I am new to Python, it is challenging to keep track of all of my variables, and still have a working script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change global variables without declaring them:

```
a = 'bad'

def bad_fn():
    a = 'good'
bad_fn()
print('bad_fn() is'+a)

def good_fn():
    global a
    a = 'good'
good_fn()
print('good_fn() is'+a)
```

results in

```
bad_fn() is bad
good_fn() is good
```

In general, using global variables in bad practice. Passing parameters explicitly makes debugging and code reuse much less of a headache. Here is rewritten version of your code which should be easier to understand:

```
# Test the Collatz conjecture:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture
import profile

# Python 2/3 compatibility shim
import sys
if sys.hexversion >= 0x3000000:
    # Python 3.x
    inp = input
    rng = range
else:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
    rng = xrange

# cache of already-seen values
seen = set([1])

def test(n):
    visited = set()
    while True:
        if n in seen:             # Ran into an already-seen chain that goes to 1
            seen.update(visited)
            return len(visited)
        elif n in visited:        # Closed loop! this should never happen
            print('Loop found at n = {}'.format(n))
            return None
        else:
            visited.add(n)

        if n % 2:         # n is odd?
            n = 3*n + 1
        else:
            n //= 2

def do_profile(upto=1000000):
    prof = profile.Profile()
    prof.run('for n in rng(2, {}): test(n)'.format(upto))
    prof.print_stats()

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(inp('Enter a number to test (or x to exit): '))
        except ValueError:
            break

        res = test(n)
        if res is None:
            print("Well, that's odd...")
        else:
            print("Chain terminated after {} values were tested".format(res))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

It took 17.7s on my machine to run `do_profile(1000000)`. It looked at a total of 2,168,611 numbers, the highest of which was 56,991,483,520. No loops were found.

**Edit:** I have added an inp() shim function; the code should now run in both Python 2 or Python 3.

**Edit2**: moved the profiling code into the main code listing and added range/xrange to the Python 2/3 shims.

Comment: Is this for Python 2 or 3, I run Python 3.3?

Comment: When I run the testing portion of your code, I get this error message:    `NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined`                              I then remove the 'x' from 'xrange', but I then get this message:      `NameError: name 'test' is not defined`

Comment: @TechnologicalGenious: I wrote and tested it in Python 2.7.5. Python 3 expects input() instead of raw_input(). I've added a translation shim to make it work for either.

Comment: It is still saying "`NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined`" and "`NameError: name 'test' is not defined`"

Comment: @TechnologicalGenious: fixed. Anything else?

Comment: There is still a problem with the 'test' function:    `NameError: name 'test' is not defined`

Comment: @TechnologicalGenious: I have no idea how you are getting that error. 'test(n)' is defined in line 19 of the code above and works perfectly for me in Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a global variable, you need to declare it preceded by `global` in your function, ie:

```
value = 0

def changeValue():
   global value
   value += 1
```

If you do not need to change the variable, `global` is not required.

Comment: yes, I know this, but I am not changing the variable, I am asking for a number, indicated by `value`, and then setting a totally seperate variable to the value of `value`

Comment: @TechnologicalGenious In your very first function, you are in fact attempting to change the variable.  I didn't look at your entire question, as I don't have the time at the moment, but I noticed that...